# Broadcast a private wireless network from Mac to iPhone via ethernet

Tags: ethernet

Situation: I use my mac's ethernet for internet, because my apartment doesn't have a working router. However, I need wifi for my iPhone. Wifi is available from other apartments in the same building, however it's a weak/slow network speed.

Question: Can I setup a wifi hotspot coming from my Mac, that is connected to the internet via ethernet? This hotspot would require a password, so only my iPhone can connect to it.

Models: mid-2012 Macbook Pro Retina. Updated to Yosemite 10.10.2. iPhone 5s, updated to current software available, I don't remember the number.

Research: I have researched this topic. Majority are out of date, or are about iPhone TO mac hotspot, rather than Mac TO iPhone. Or they discuss from wifi to wifi. Seems no one uses ethernet anymore. (Ethernet OP btw).

Thank you! Hope I provided enough information.

Comment: You're confusing yourself with terminology.  Buy a router plug it in, plug the mac into it and connect the iPhone via wifi.

Comment: No I am not. I believe you failed to recognize the question.

Comment: Tyson probably could have worded that better, but he raises a valid point - your "Mac's ethernet" has to come from somewhere. Your Mac does not spontaneously generate internet by itself. What is the ethernet cord plugged into at the other end? Generally, a modem provided by your ISP. It may have router capabilities. If it does not, you could put a router that has WiFi between where the cord is plugged in and your Mac, which in turn would provide WiFi to your iPhone.

Comment: Yes, it is a modem. But I figured stating my router was broken would have somewhat interpreted that. My apologizes for being unclear. Modem->ethernet-> computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac, go to System Preferences > Sharing. In the list on the left-hand side, check the box for Internet Sharing, then ensure your current connection (probably listed as Ethernet) is selected in the combobox. In the checklist below that, check the box for Wi-Fi.

(In the screenshot, Internet Sharing on the left is not checked, but it must be for this to work.)

The Wi-Fi Options button allows you to set the network name (SSID) and password.

[image]

Comment: This was the answer! Thank you! It's even fast and somewhat secure. (Wish it was WEP2). But, beggers can't be choosers. Thanks again!

Comment: I've done this before myself when we had Ethernet and no wifi router available. It was nice and fast and worked great- reliable.